# Unable to launch Spyder from newly created python3.6 environment in Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

```
(py36) C:\Users\User>spyder
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\py36\python.exe 
C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\py36\Scripts\spyder-script.py
```

It launched properly after creating the environment, but after installing theano, tensorflow and keras, it does not launch. It keeps showing the above error.
The commands I used to install the libraries were:

```
conda install theano
conda install tensorflow
conda install keras
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try resetting you spyder.

try the command below in your terminal.
`spyder --reset`

Comment: It doesn't work. Even if I try to check the spyder version, the prompt  gets stuck.